# EF Model is assigned null. Is there any way to assign model with data from other model

Tags: entity-framework, model, nullreferenceexception

```
ApplicantsRegistration applicantsRegistration = new ApplicantsRegistration();
applicantsRegistration = _context.ApplicantsRegistrations.FirstOrDefault();
```

When I found it null then trying to bind like this.

```
 if (applicantsRegistration == null)
        {
            applicantsRegistration.Name = formPost.Name;    //null reference exceptions...
            applicantsRegistration.Email = formPost.Email;
            ....
        }
```

Any solution without reinitialize it into if?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new instance if it is found to be null. Because the change tracker of entity framework once you add it to the tracker will then know about it.